# Is there a way to fix this date display bug in Microsoft Teams (web)

Tags: microsoft-teams

When I look at message history in Teams, it doesn't always show the full date. As in this example:

[image]

Upon looking at this, it appears that I have messaged this person today. But, in fact, this is a message from a week ago from today. I find this very annoying and confusing. There have been multiple times me and my team have gotten confused and given inaccurate information to each other. In the settings in the web app, it shows "Language" as a general selection, but gives no option to change the date display format. I am using the web version of Teams. Is there a way that I can have this always display the date in "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt" format, instead of "Dddd hh:mm tt" format?